# Displaying contents of array (using PHP foreach?)

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, foreach

I'm working on a WordPress site and am using a plugin called 'Simple Fields', to add data to repeatable fields.  I've entered data into three fields: (audioinfo, audiofile, audiocomposer).

I would now like to create a post that displays that information in the following way:

Audio Info 1

Audio File 1

Audio Composer 1

~~~

Audio Info 2

Audio File 2

Audio Composer 2

I've been trying to figure this out with foreach.  Here's the closest I can arrive at (thought I know it's invalid).  Can anyone make any suggestions of how to handle this?

```
<?php 
$audioinfo = simple_fields_values("audioinfo");
$audiofile = simple_fields_values("audiofile");
$audiocomposer = simple_fields_values("audiocomposer") 
foreach ($audioinfo as $audioinfos, $audiofile as $audiofiles, $audiocomposer as $audiocomposers){
echo $audioinfos;
echo $audiofile;
echo $audiocomposer;
}
?>
```

(Just as a side note, in case it's important, the first three lines appear to all be valid - that is, if I do a "foreach" on $audiocomposer alone, I successfully get: Bach Handel Beethoven.)

Is there something I can do to apply "foreach" to all three at the same time?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming all the arrays of same length, making use of a normal for loop.

```
<?php 
$audioinfo = simple_fields_values("audioinfo");
$audiofile = simple_fields_values("audiofile");
$audiocomposer = simple_fields_values("audiocomposer");

for($i=0;$i<count($audioinfo);$i++)
{
echo $audioinfo[$i];
echo $audiofile[$i];
echo $audiocomposer[$i];
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. 
Yes indeed, all arrays will always be the same length.
I like your nice and simple code.  

However, when I use it, I get a blank return.  No parse error or anything like that.  It's just the div where I've placed the php code is rendered empty.
Have you any suggestions?  Is there a different syntax for the `for($i=0;$i<count($audioinfo);$i++)` that I could try?
Is more info about the plugin necessary?
Thanks.

Comment: @Chris, Sorry it should be $i. I have edited the answer. Can you try again ?

Comment: Just for reference, in case any other Simple Fields user stumbles upon this: Shankar is totally right!  This is a perfect answer to this question, in general.
However, when I asked the question, I didn't know that Simple Fields uses more complex Arrays than I'd thought.
So, while it hasn't solved my particular situation, it is the winner.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there are always going to be the same number of items in all 3 arrays, you could do something like this:

```
$items = count($audioinfo);
for ($i = 0; $i < $items; $i++)
{
    echo $audioinfo[$i];
    echo $audiofile[$i];
    echo $audiocomposer[$i];
}
```

Comment: Hi Mark, and thanks for the quick reply!

This looks beautifully eloquent.  I've plugged it in as follows:

`<?php 
$audioinfo = simple_fields_values("audioinfo");
$audiofile = simple_fields_values("audiofile");
$audiocomposer = simple_fields_values("audiocomposer");

$items = count($audioinfo);
for ($i = 0; $ < $items; $i++)
{
    echo $audioinfo[$i];
    echo $audiofile[$i];
    echo $audiocomposer[$i];
}
?>
`
However, this returns the following error upon viewing the page:
**unexpected '<', expecting T_VARIABLE or '$'**

Hmm... Do you need more info about how the plugin works?

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo in the `for...` line. Should be `$i < $items` - have updated the post.

Comment: @Mark - Thanks!
There must be another piece to this puzzle, because all iterations of echo $audiocomposer[$i] are being displayed at the top of all other output as such: "ArrayBach ArrayMozart ArrayRachmaninov" Incidentally, the same thing happens when I try to implement Yaroslav's solution. Do you have any further suggestions? 

NB - I found a way to return all field group data. I've added it to the bottom of my original question. Does this info help?

Comment: @Chris if you are presented with something like 'blablaArraybla' as the result of and `echo` then you surely have one of the components an array instead of a string, and my bet is that `$audioinfo[$i]` or `$audiofile[$i]`... it seems the composers are well enough.

Comment: @khael Thanks for this. You're right, of course.  It's $audiofile that's acting up.
I've discovered that the "audiofile" field returns an array of info.

So, to echo the URL of an item in the "audiofile" field, I need to use:
`echo $audiofile['url']`

Knowing this, I tried to change the above _for_ statement to this:

`$items = count($audioinfo);
for ($i = 0; $i < $items; $i++)
{
    echo $audioinfo[$i];
    echo $audiofile['url'][$i];
    echo $audiocomposer[$i];
}`

But no such luck.

Is there a way to request iteration $i of the 'url' part of the "audiofile" array?

Answer (score 1):

One more pretty solution:

```
<?php 
$audioinfo = simple_fields_values("audioinfo");
$audiofile = simple_fields_values("audiofile");
$audiocomposer = simple_fields_values("audiocomposer");

foreach ($audioinfo as $k => $val){
  echo $val;
  echo $audiofile[$k];
  echo $audiocomposer[$k];
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

here i gave one example how to handle the 3 array value in single foreach , hope it will much help to you

```
$audioinfo =array('popsong','rocksong','molodysong');
  $audiofile=array('jackson','rahman','example');
  $audiocomposer =array('first','second','third');

  foreach($audioinfo as $key => $value)
   {
    echo $value."</br>";
    echo $audiofile[$key]."</br>";
    echo $audiocomposer[$key]."</br>";

   }
```